# Why doesn't gather() use the key variable name?

Tags: r, tidyr

It's shameful, but I still can't wrap my mind fully around `tidyr`, specifically `gather()`. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

If I run this tiny snippet of code

```
library(tidyr)
x <- data.frame(var1=letters[1:3], var2=LETTERS[7:9], var3=21:23)
gather(x, foo, value)
```

I get

```
> x
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    G   21
2    b    H   22
3    c    I   23

> gather(x, foo, value)
  variable value
1     var1     a
2     var1     b
3     var1     c
4     var2     G
5     var2     H
6     var2     I
7     var3    21
8     var3    22
9     var3    23
```

Where does `foo` get used? Is this completely unnecessary? Am I tripping up because I'm thinking `reshape` style where you define the `ID` variables and the rest get `melt`ed whereas I should be thinking differently where you define the variables to `gather` and the rest are considered `ID`?

Comment: With `tidyr_0.3.1.9000`, I have a column with `foo` as well as a warning message (Warning message: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped).

Comment: Okay, I'm using `tidyr_0.2.0`, so maybe this is more obvious in later versions? So what does the `key` variable do?

Comment: Maybe this is a version issue, because I also can't replicate the first simple example here: http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/

Comment: I see. You can then try the dev version by running `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")`.

Comment: Why do you need to go to github? Version 0.3.1 is [available on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html). And your example above works as expected: the first column in the output is named `foo` and the second column is named `value`.

Comment: You might have seen this problem if you also had reshape loaded. Either way it's fixed in 0.3.1

Comment: Thanks @hadley. Indeed, when I try it without reshape loaded it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that occurs when `reshape` and `tidyr` are both loaded. It has been fixed in `tidyr 0.3.1`.